# When is the midge season in Scotland?

Tags: hiking, uk, bugs, scotland, midges

What time of year are the the dreaded [midge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highland_midge)'s in Scotland at their worst?

I've only really been into the Higlands in Winter and I would prefer to avoid the worst time for these if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not really a defined time in which midges are out and about, but usually they are seen from early June until October. Midge season heavily depends on the weather and a wet and cold June will mean less midgets or a later start to the season (as it happens this year).

For a really good resource to know about midges is the [Midge Forecast](http://midgeforecast.co.uk/) that gives some estimate about the menace of midges in different areas.

Comment: I'd agree with Gilad that in general this is correct, however some areas have much longer seasons. Where we are midges start to become too much for sitting outside and having drinks on the patio as early as late April, and even this year was late May. 

Skye and the west have much worse midges than the east and central areas, and the far north has only minimal areas that suffer from midges, so Gilad's forecast link is essential!

Comment: That's good info, I always thought the west was better for midges (sea breeze?!). But I stand corrected! @RoryAlsop