# What is the best way to manage Scottish midges?

Tags: camping, backpacking, wild-camping, bugs, midges

I have seen some posts that mention midges and midge spray. I am wild camping in Scotland in August. Should I be worried about them? Is there anything else a part from midge spray I can use to keep them away?

Comment: I have no personal experience but I have heard that all of summer Scotland is dreadful for midges. Also, a deterrent is `Avon Skin So Soft` which is used by the SAS to keep bugs off that I've used and is very good.

Comment: as long as you walk, the midges won't be able to keep up with you.

Comment: I don't know the difference between Scotish midges and other mosquitos somewhere else but here in New Zealand and back in Brazil, I found cooking oil very efficient. A couple of drops of standard cooking oil (canola, soya or vegetable), spread on the exposed parts and you are away. It doesn't smell amazingly good but it works for me.

Comment: A head net and full body covering clothing are the only thing that really works, in my experience. I've never been anywhere where the bugs were quite as nasty as in Scotland. (I don't think I had gloves actually, but that might be an idea as well.)

Comment: In Canada, we have the black fly variety.  Easiest things to do are move, cover up and use mint (Spearmint / Peppermint) oil.  You can water down some Mint oil and have home made repellent.  Works very well short term (30 mins) obviously affected by other factors.

Answer (score 14):

I've been battling the little buggers for half a century. Here's what I've learned.

**Take them seriously!**

Most of the time they're only a minor irritant, but at their worst they're very nasty. I've twice had to help people in toxic shock from midge attack. Make sure you're prepared.

**Know your enemy**

- They don't like sunlight, so are are more active at dawn and dusk, in shade and on overcast days.
- The higher the humidity the more active they become, and they can fly in light rain. They become inactive when humidity falls below 60% or so.
- The population falls away rapidly above 700m (2300 ft)or so.
- They can't fly in wind speeds above 6mph (10kph), but can still get you on breezy days if you take shelter.
- They can't bite through clothing, but they will crawl through any gaps in your defences.

**Take avoiding action**

- **Avoid the crowds!**: intensity varies from place to place and from season to season. Use the [Smidge Midge Forecast](https://www.smidgeup.com/midge-forecast/) to avoid the worst areas - not 100% accurate but still pretty useful.
- **Cover up**: when things get bad, no repellent will keep them all off. Carry a broad-brimmed hat and headnet, some light liner gloves and full-coverage clothing.
- **Defend your living space**: a tent with full insect netting is essential. They can get through mosquito netting - you need the finer midge/noseeum netting. In bad conditions it's impossible to avoid carrying dozens of midges into your tent on your clothing. The easiest way to deal with them is to burn mosquito coils for a few minutes - you can get holders that reduce the fire risk. Alternatively, if you keep covered up the midges will eventually settle in the seams of your tent. Running your fingers along the seams will eliminate most of the problem.
- **Use insect repellent**: DEET is the most effective for most, but quite unpleasant and toxic. So you might consider the [alternatives](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/978/what-proven-alternatives-are-there-to-deet).
- **Camp on exposed sites**: midges can't fly in a breeze, so whenever safe and practical choose exposed sites for your camp.

Personally, during midge season I like to head for the ridges and plateaus and camp high. Though provided you steer clear of the worst areas you shouldn't have too many problems, even in the valleys. But prepare for the worst or you could end up in trouble.

Answer (score 8):

Most of your question is covered in [When is the midge season in Scotland?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/when-is-the-midge-season-in-scotland). But I'll answer the non-duplicate question:

> Is there anything else a part from midge spray I can use to keep them
>   away?

Yes quite a few alternatives, these are covered pretty well in [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/978/what-proven-alternatives-are-there-to-deet). To name a few:

> - Lemon Eucalyptus oil
> - Avon Skin So Soft (I kid you not!)
> - [Citronella oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citronella_oil)

Now that said, literally THE best insepct repellant is [DEET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEET) it's nasty horrible stuff but nothing keeps bugs away better. If you want to avoid the midgies (and you will). This is your best bet.

Also buy a mosquito net and take clothing that covers your arms and legs. Tuck everything in. Here is the result of me not tucking my top into my pants one evening:

[image]

Comment: uh, how nasty. And Avon Skin So Soft seems to be really THE secret tip of the locals :D

Answer (score 3):

You can buy candles that contain citronella. I was pretty sceptical about their effectiveness, but last weekend, we lit two outside the tent and we were able to sit outside relatively unmolested.

Best advice - camp somewhere exposed - midgies can't cope with much more than a gentle breeze.

And for the love of God, take a midge net - they're hot and uncomfortable and you look stupid, but better that than be eaten alive by a swarm whilst you're packing up your tent each morning.